# Verilog Adder testbench

Tags: verilog

```
//In here, `WORD_LEN is 32.

`include "Defines.v"

module Adder (in1, in2, out);
  input [`WORD_LEN-1:0] in1, in2;
  output [`WORD_LEN-1:0] out;

  assign out = in1 + in2;
endmodule
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module AdderTest;
  reg in1, in2;
  wire out;
  Adder TestAdder(.in1(in1), .in2(in2), .out(out));

  initial begin
  in1 = 4'b0000; in2 = 4'b0000; #100;
  in1 = 4'b0011; in2 = 4'b1111; #100;
  in1 = 4'b1000; in2 = 4'b1100; #100;
  $stop;
  end


endmodule
```

When I simulate this, Only in1[0] and in2[0] gets the value. Except for them, they got a blue line.
Also, out got a red line. I really don't get what's wrong with this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Although you define `in1`, `in2`, and `out` as 32-bit ports in your module (as indicated by your comment), the connected signals in your testbench are only 1 bit wide. Therefore, only the first bit of your module's input signals (i.e., `in1[0]` and `in2[0]`) are driven.

Try to use the following testbench:

```
module AdderTest;
  reg  [31:0] in1, in2; // CHANGE
  wire [31:0] out;      // CHANGE
  Adder TestAdder(.in1(in1), .in2(in2), .out(out));

  initial begin
    in1 = 4'b0000; in2 = 4'b0000; #100;
    in1 = 4'b0011; in2 = 4'b1111; #100;
    in1 = 4'b1000; in2 = 4'b1100; #100;
    $stop;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Also, take a look at the log file your compiler/simulator generates. Many compilers throw a warning if the port size and a connected signal does not match.